# Can't use my Web Reference

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, visual-studio-2015, wsdl

I'm experiencing some issues in using a web reference in  a c# project in Visual Studio 2015.

[Reference](http://demo.visualsoft.co.uk/api/soap/wsdl/3)

I add my reference as usual and Visual Studio finds 1 Service and 2 Datasets. I can add the service and the solution explorer shows the service `StockExchangeSoapServer.wsdl` (and datasets `3.xsd` and `30.xsd`) under my web reference.

[image]

[image]

When I come to use the service in code, Visual Studio can't find the service as it usually does. On any mention of my web reference folder/service, I get the error

> "namespace doesn't exist..."

and when I scope to it in the Object Browser I can't find any evidence of my web reference.

[image]

So far I have tried:

1. adding `?wsdl` to the end of my url
2. adding as a service reference

Any help in shedding some light on what is wrong and if/how it can be fixed would be most appreciated - is it something to do with the inclusion of datasets?

Comment: If you add links, I will edit the images into the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @stuartd !
Add Web Reference: [link] (http://imgur.com/EeC0KXM)
Solution Explorer: [link] (http://imgur.com/nMmxFbh)
Object Browser: [link] (http://imgur.com/pPE9OHV)
Example Error: [link] (http://imgur.com/a/OlRxa)

Comment: same problem here... did you find any solution?

Comment: @rasputino - unfortunately not sorry. I suspected it was something either unsupported or incorrect with the WSDL. I completed the API calls required successfully in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a problem with the WSDL

Completing the required tasks in PHP worked just fine